# How to make custom fontawsome Icons?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a requirement to create custom fontawsome icons. Icons which is similar to  fontawsome and i need to know how to include the custom icons to my project.
More clearly, icons should be made of images or alphanumeric numbers in a pattern to meet the desired symbol. Simalar to stacking of icons in fontawsome. But the rquirements is icons should be completly customized and able to use like fontawsome icons.

Comment: fontawsome icons use of font file and every icon is one character of that font. You can open file of font in any font editor and add your custom icon to it.

Answer (score 1):

https://icomoon.io/

this website let you upload your own svg files to generate font icons

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [fontastic](https://fontastic.me) it might help you :)